# How to change the orientation of page contents after changing app language flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make my application support many different languages that the user can choose his favorite from among them.
I use the following method for dealing with languages:

```
easy_localization: ^2.3.2
```

```
  EasyLocalization(
      saveLocale: true,
      supportedLocales: [

        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('ar', 'SA')
],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
      child: LoginScreen(),
    ),
```

I need to change the direction of the page content in case the Arabic language is from left to right and in case it is English from right to left.

How can I do that if someone has a solution please help me. I am a new flutter programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add conditions for every widget that you want to customize depending on localization. Something like this:

```
   context.locale == Locale('en', 'US')
        ? Text(LocaleKeys.title).tr(context: context)
        : Text('Test'),
```

Completed code with a little change from [here](https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/blob/develop/example/lib/main.dart):

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'lang_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization_loader/easy_localization_loader.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';

import 'generated/locale_keys.g.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      child: MyApp(),
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('ar', 'DZ'),
        Locale('de', 'DE'),
        Locale('ru', 'RU')
      ],
      path: 'resources/langs/langs.csv',
      assetLoader: CsvAssetLoader()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log(context.locale.toString(), name: '${this} # locale Context');
    log('title'.tr().toString(), name: '${this} # locale');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'title'.tr(),
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Easy localization'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int counter = 0;
  bool _gender = true;

  void incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  void switchGender(bool val) {
    setState(() {
      _gender = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Like in here!
        title: context.locale == Locale('en', 'US')
            ? Text(LocaleKeys.title).tr(context: context)
            : Text('Test'),
        //Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('title')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.language),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => LanguageView(), fullscreenDialog: true),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Text(
              LocaleKeys.gender_with_arg,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  fontSize: 19,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ).tr(args: ['aissat'], gender: _gender ? 'female' : 'male'),
            Text(
              tr(LocaleKeys.gender, gender: _gender ? 'female' : 'male'),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(FontAwesome.male),
                Switch(value: _gender, onChanged: switchGender),
                Icon(FontAwesome.female),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Text(LocaleKeys.msg).tr(args: ['aissat', 'Flutter']),
            Text(LocaleKeys.msg_named)
                .tr(namedArgs: {'lang': 'Dart'}, args: ['Easy localization']),
            Text(LocaleKeys.clicked).plural(counter),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                incrementCounter();
              },
              child: Text(LocaleKeys.clickMe).tr(),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Text(
                plural(LocaleKeys.amount, counter,
                    format: NumberFormat.currency(
                        locale: Intl.defaultLocale, symbol: '€')),
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.deleteSaveLocale();
              },
              child: Text(LocaleKeys.reset_locale).tr(),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: Text('+1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomPreloaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPreloaderWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log('Loading custom preloder widget');
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use   Platform.localeName.contains('en') inside a condition

```
import 'dart:io';
if (Platform.localeName.contains('ar'))
  Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
    size: 25,
  ),
if (Platform.localeName.contains('en'))
  Icon(
    Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
    size: 25,
  ),
```